# Localizable Option Strict in VB.NET IDE

Tags: vb.net

With creating new project VB.NET IDE automatically set Option Strict to Off by default.
So I often put **Option Strict On** at top of my files as a good programming practice and for that files the rule of Option Strict is applied.

Now (for some time), when creating a new project I set Option Strict to On under project's properties/compile so that is applied to whole project without need to specify that on every file.

But Now I use one foreign program under my project where data types are not fully known for me and I would like to keep Option Strict for all files in project except for that one.

I try with **Option Strict Off** at top of that file but that seem not enough. There are listed much of typical errors under my IDE/Errors tab.

How to turn off Option Strict for just one file under project which have Option Strict turned **On** under Compiler properties of project?

```
Public Class ApplicationBar
Inherits NativeWindow

' Debugging Mode On/Off
#Const DEBUG_MODE = False

' SetWindowLong selectors
Const GWL_WNDPROC = -4&

' Windows messages
Const WM_ACTIVATE = &H6
Const WM_GETMINMAXINFO = &H24
Const WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE = &H231
Const WM_EXITSIZEMOVE = &H232
Const WM_MOVING = &H216
Const WM_NCHITTEST = &H84
Const WM_NCMOUSEMOVE = &HA0
Const WM_SIZING = &H214
Const WM_TIMER = &H113
Const WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED = &H47

' WM_SIZING Selectors
Const WMSZ_LEFT = 1
Const WMSZ_RIGHT = 2
Const WMSZ_TOP = 3
Const WMSZ_TOPLEFT = 4
Const WMSZ_TOPRIGHT = 5
Const WMSZ_BOTTOM = 6
Const WMSZ_BOTTOMLEFT = 7
Const WMSZ_BOTTOMRIGHT = 8

' Appbar messages
Const ABM_NEW = &H0
Const ABM_REMOVE = &H1
Const ABM_QUERYPOS = &H2
Const ABM_SETPOS = &H3
Const ABM_GETSTATE = &H4
Const ABM_GETTASKBARPOS = &H5
Const ABM_ACTIVATE = &H6
Const ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR = &H7
Const ABM_SETAUTOHIDEBAR = &H8
Const ABM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED = &H9
Const ABM_SETSTATE = &HA

' Appbar edges
Const ABE_LEFT = 0
Const ABE_TOP = 1
Const ABE_RIGHT = 2
Const ABE_BOTTOM = 3
Const ABE_UNKNOWN = 4
Const ABE_FLOAT = 5

'Appbar allowed floats
Const ABF_ALLOWLEFT = 1
Const ABF_ALLOWRIGHT = 2
Const ABF_ALLOWTOP = 4
Const ABF_ALLOWBOTTOM = 8
Const ABF_ALLOWFLOAT = 16

' The ABN_* constants are defined here as follows:
'Const ABN_STATECHANGE = &H0
Const ABN_POSCHANGED = &H1
Const ABN_FULLSCREENAPP = &H2
Const ABN_WINDOWARRANGE = &H3

' GetKeyState and GetAsyncKeyState Selectors
Const VK_LBUTTON = &H1
Const VK_RBUTTON = &H2
Const VK_CONTROL = &H11

' MessageBox Selectors
Const MB_OK = &H0&
Const MB_ICONINFORMATION = &H40&

' ModifyStyle Selectors
Const GWL_STYLE = (-16)
Const GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20)
Const WS_CAPTION = &HC00000
Const WS_SYSMENU = &H80000
Const WS_EX_APPWINDOW = &H40000
Const WS_BORDER = &H800000


' SetWindowPos Selectors
Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
Const SWP_NOZORDER = &H4
Const SWP_NOACTIVATE = &H10
Const SWP_DRAWFRAME = &H20

Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2
Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
Const HWND_BOTTOM = 1

' ShowWindow Selectors
Const SW_HIDE = 0
Const SW_SHOW = 5

' WM_ACTIVATE Selectors
Const WA_INACTIVE = 0

'Custom Defaults
Private Const AB_DEF_SIZE_INC As Integer = 1
Private Const AB_DEF_DOCK_SIZE As Integer = 32

' We need a timer to determine when the AppBar should be re-hidden
Const AUTO_HIDE_TIMER_ID = 100
Const SLIDE_DEF_TIMER_INTERVAL = 400 ' milliseconds

' Subclassing function default result
Const INHERIT_DEFAULT_CALLBACK = -1
```

All those variables are underlined with green as NOT explicitely declared and are treated as errors under Option Strict On.

Comment: +1 for using Option strict.

Comment: @MarkHall And probably -10 for using VB.NET ;-)

Comment: @UweKeim It's a low blow, but funny none the less.  I suppose, any language that can't say for sure if `blah()` is a method or an array deserves any derision that it receives.

Comment: Hi Uwe, please be kind and keep it for yourself :) I can do programing in C# but VB.NET sounds more natural with brilliant lexical features which give us all the power of good communication between computer and humans.

Comment: Well, @UweKeim did put a smiley face, after all :)

Comment: @UweKeim The choice of language in my mind is not relevant. What I was stating was that I see so much code here that just by enabling it would get rid of a lot of their issues.  :)

Comment: Sorry, guys, just tried to do some sooooooooo obvious joke. As always, I failed greatly. No offense, I'm using VB.NET (and even VBScript) from time to time, too.

Comment: Have you tried removing it from the project level and assigning it either on or off to each individual file. ?

Comment: You can set `Option Strict On` as the default: please see the section "To set the Option Strict default setting for new projects" at [Option Strict Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx).

Comment: @Andrew that is what I think he has done. I was suggesting that he remove it and set it per file. It may be overriding the one file he is trying to turn it off on.

Comment: @MarkHall Then I was thrown by the OP's first sentence: "With creating new project VB.NET IDE automatically set Option Strict to Off by default," but I can sort-of see it as being readable as if the code was copy-and-pasted into another project on another computer where the IDE setting had not been changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting Option Strict Off at the top of the file will work correctly. We do exactly the same as you (add Option Strict On at the top of all code files) and also require it to be set on in new projects.

However, there are occasionally scenarios where Option Strict Off is required (certain activities with Crystal Reports, for example). In these cases, we isolate just the code that requires Option Strict Off, move it to its own file, and add the directive to the top.

** UPDATE based on new code:

The solution to the problem is to add the following to the top of the file in addition to `Option Strict Off`:

```
Option Infer On
```

This will allow VB to automatically determine and assign appropriate data types to each of the objects.

HOWEVER: if you are using these values in Windows API calls, you must ensure the types that VB picks for you are correct. You can do this by hovering the cursor over the declaration: VB will show the full type declaration.

If this file originated in another VB project, then the originating project almost certainly had Option Infer On set in the project properties.

Comment: Then I simply don't understand why that scenario don't work for me.

Comment: Try adding Option Explicit Off to the top of the file as well.

Comment: Please ignore the previous comment and see the updated answer.

Comment: Didn't get much with Option Infer On. Under Properties/Compile I can set Option Strict to "custom" by setting Implicit conversions and Implicit type;object assumed to "none" and then errors gone but that don't seem's good I think. I put all this code to http://www.kalko.com.hr/AppBar.txt so maybe you can see anything? It will be there for some time...

Comment: Using VS2010, the only reported problem in that code was Public AppBarHeight. Adding As Integer to this resolves the problem.

Comment: Hm, it seem's that I broke something really serious in order to reorganize project.

Answer (score 5):

What you describe should work fine.  It is very common to have `Option Strict On` for the whole project, but then just override it to `Option Strict Off` on certain files.  Therefore your problem is most likely something else.  For instance, perhaps your problem is not with `Option Strict`, but rather with one of the other options, such as `Option Explicit` or `Option Infer`.

Comment: Interesting. I conclude that this may be Option Strict because when I turn it Off under compiler tab all those messages dissapear. Messages are like: "Variable declaration without an 'As' clause; type of Object assumed."

Comment: It seem's not. This is one "AppBar" program which haven't many variables explicitely declared with AS and those are errors. I attach a part of code to my question.

Comment: I copied that code into a test project, where it was `Option Strict On` for the project.  I saw all the errors saying "Option Strict On requires all variable declarations to have an 'As' clause."  I then added `Option Strict Off` to the first line of the file and all the errors went away.

Comment: Are you saying that when you add `Option Strict Off` to the top of that file, those errors don't go away for you?

Comment: Yes. After many tries I still have errors typical for Option Script On. If I turn Off Option Strict on Properties/Compile then errors disappears.

Comment: And you're sure that you are definitely putting `Option Strict Off` (not `On`) as the first line in that file?  And what are the errors that it gives, exactly, when that is the first line in the file?

Comment: Of course I have Option Strict Off (not On) at top of file. Errors are: "Variable declaration without an 'As' clause; type of Object assumed." I copy that file from another project through project explorer. Can this be important? I copy some other files same way which all behaves as expected.

Comment: Don't copy the file to another project.  Just change the `Option Strict` setting for the current project to `Off`.  That would be a much better test to see if *that's* the setting that actually fixes it.